# Unable to drop in Listvieitem when auto scroll occur in list view

Tags: wpf, listview, drag-and-drop, uwp, microsoft-metro

I am unable to drop in ListViewItem when auto scroll occurs in list view in UWP app.

I am able to drag and drop to the end and top but not to the middle.
Unable to drop in the positions where auto scrolling ocures.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: Share what you have tried yet

Comment: https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop

Comment: @NareshRavlani I am developing an UWP app Which has a list box with many items .it can be reorder using drag and drop. .List box is small and contain may items so scroll viewer is there,When tried to drag & drop on the middle of the list.it automatically scroll to end of the list.this issue occurs in default implementation of listview itself.tried in a sample by just placing a list box and adding some items and make the list reordering enabled..

Answer (score 0):

[ListBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listbox) doesn't have `CanReorderItems` property, so I think you are using `ListView`. When you drag the item to the edge of the `ListView`, it do will auto scroll. But it doesn't scroll to the end of the list as you described, it can be controlled by your operation. Drag the item back the scroll viewer will stop scroll and you can drop the item to the place auto scrolling occurs as following picture shows.
[image]